# C++ std::vector of independent std::threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, stdthread

I'm building a real time software where I have a main infinite loops on `main()` and threads used to read and process data.

One of the issues is keeping a `std::vector` of running threads to send signals to them and to monitor execution. So I put together this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

namespace readerThread {

    void start(int id)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            std::cout << "Reader " << id << " running..." <<  std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
    }

}


int main() 
{

        int readers[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
        
        std::vector<std::thread> readerThreads;

        for (int &reader : readers)
        {
            std::thread th(readerThread::start, reader);
            readerThreads.push_back(th);
        }

        while(true)
        {
            std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
        }
        
        return 0;
}
```

It doesn´t even compile, getting this error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/string:41,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::thread; _Args = {const std::thread&}; _Tp = std::thread]':
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:256:4:   required from 'static std::_Require<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__has_construct<_Tp, _Args ...> > std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Args = {const std::thread&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>; std::_Require<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__has_construct<_Tp, _Args ...> > = void]'
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:402:16:   required from 'static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Args = {const std::thread&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]'
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:917:30:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::thread]'
main.cpp:37:30:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/thread:126:5: note: declared here
     thread(const thread&) = delete;
     ^
```

The threads are independent, so I don't need to call `join` on the main program nor on any thread...

So, here are my doubts:

Why my code does not compile?

Is that the correct way to store the vector of threads ?

Thanks for helping...

PS:[Original code here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8064cce3edd2c47):

Comment: If you plan to stop your application correctly, you should call `join()`  before thread object will destroy. Or call `detach()` for detach thread from object. Otherwise you will get `terminate()` call in thread destructor.

Comment: gomons, did not get your point. join() will hold the main thread execution, and that´s not desired here...

Comment: You can also use `readerThreads.emplace_back(readerThread::start, reader);`, What gomons means is that you must either `join()` or `detach()` a thread instance before its destructor executes, otherwise `terminate()` is called. But your threads seem quite happy to run forever, so this is not a problem in the example above.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use something like

```
readerThreads.push_back(move(th));
```

This will make `th` an rvalue, and cause the move ctor to be called. The copy ctor of `thread` was [disabled](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/) by design (see Anthony Williams' [C++ Concurrency In Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/)).

Comment: Yes! Now I remember that from other readings.. Thanks for helping... Working like a charm...

Answer (score 10):

```
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::thread; _Args = {const std::thread&}; _Tp = std::thread]':
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:256:4:   required from 'static std::_Require<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__has_construct<_Tp, _Args ...> > std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Args = {const std::thread&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>; std::_Require<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__has_construct<_Tp, _Args ...> > = void]'
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:402:16:   required from 'static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Args = {const std::thread&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]'
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:917:30:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::thread]'
main.cpp:37:30:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Lets peel this back a bit.

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'
```

Your code is doing something that attempts to introduce a `std::thread`.

```
required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&)
```

`push_back` is the culprit.

`std::thread` is not copyable - what would it *mean* to copy a thread?

```
std::thread t1([](){});
std::thread t2 = t1;
```

So instances of `std::thread` objects are intended to be unique owners. Aside from the simple confusion, much pain would ensue.

They are, however, movable.

```
std::thread t1([](){});
std::thread t2 = std::move(t1);
```

`t1` is no-longer a valid thread descriptor, the thread it was describing is now owned by `t2`.

For placing such things into a container you can either use `std::move` or `std::emplace`/`std::emplace_back`.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.push_back(std::move(std::thread([](){})));
threads.emplace_back([](){});
```

While your code is focusing on this particular issue, let me point out that the C++ standard declares it as an error for a thread destructor to be invoked while a thread is still attached and not joined.

```
int main() {
    std::thread t1([](){ while (true) { std::this_thread::yield(); } };
}
```

When main terminates, t1.~thread() is called, which detects that the thread is still attached and not joined, this raises an exception causing a shutdown crash.

You either need to `join()` the thread, waiting for it to terminate running, or `detach()` it. You'll need some way to tell the thread to stop if you want to use `join()` and if you `detach()` the program may exit in the middle of the thread doing something like writing data etc, you may introduce a serious bug.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

int main () {
  std::promise<void> cnx_promise;
  std::shared_future<void> cnx_future;

  std::thread t1([cnx_future]() {
      while (cnx_future.valid()) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
      }
  });

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  cnx_promise.set_value();

  t1.join();
}
```

Here we use a promise to let the thread know when it's time to stop running, but you could use condition variables, signals, etc, or even just a simple `std::atomic<bool> ok_to_run { true };` that you test for false.

Answer (score 10):

Another variant that works is to create your thread object in the vector.push_back call. No need to call std::move in this case because its already an rvalue (thus it will be be moved).

```
for (int &reader : readers)
    readerThreads.push_back(std::thread(readerThread::start, reader));
```

Comment: Simplest and best answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is guarantee that every thread will be created in vector's storage. No object byte will be copied.

```
for (int &reader : readers)
    readerThreads.emplace_back( readerThread::start, reader );
```

In common case this not the same as @Seth suggested. But in current case it is 99% the same.